# preg_replace on everything prior to character

Tags: php, arrays, regex, function, preg-replace

I am trying to remove parts of a string which has an ID and : before it. So for example:

```
2846:ZE1,2847:ZE2,2848:ZE3,713:DY10,412:CF10
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
ZE1,ZE2,ZE3,DY10,CF10
```

I have tried the following preg_replace:

```
$remove = preg_replace('/[0-9]\:+/', '', $postcodes_id);
```

But this only removes the last digit and not all of it:

```
284ZE1,284ZE2,284ZE3,71DY10,41CF10
```

any help would be great?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$remove = preg_replace('/[0-9]+\:/', '', $postcodes_id);
```

Adding the `+` means "one or more digit" instead of your code which is "just one".

I'm pretty sure you don't need the `\` before the `:`...

Comment: As your answer was first I will accept your answer, thanks for your help. Got a bit confused reading tuts on regex so appreciate the comments.

Answer (score 2):

#### A non regex solution

```
parse_str(str_replace(array(':',','),array('=','&'),$str1),$str1);
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/132020)

Answer (score 1):

You have the `+` in the wrong place, it should be:

```
preg_replace('/[0-9]+:/', '', $postcodes_id);
```

You also don't need to escape `:`, it has no special meaning in regular expressions.